# select from table the columns stored in a variable using explode php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, html

I am using this code to get data from SQL Server and display it in a table

```
<?php  
$query = "SELECT Country,OrderNumber,Region,ShipDate,ProducedDate FROM database.Orders"; 
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['OrderNumber'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ShipDate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ProducedDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; } 
?>
```

I have a variable where is stored the columns I need separated by comma for example $col = "Country,OrderNumber,Region,ShipDate,ProducedDate"

I want to explode this variable then use `foreach` inside the first `foreach` to get the data instead of using many times `echo "<td>" . $row['****'] . "</td>";`

I have been trying it my way but couldn't make it work.

```
<?php  
$Col= "Country,OrderNumber,Region,ShipDate,ProducedDate"
$query = "SELECT $Col FROM database.Orders"; 
$cols = explode(",",$col);

foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($cols as $c ) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$c] . "</td>";  
    }
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

Any suggestions please ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want the data from the query to be re-useable later so you can close the loop? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: @clearshot66  basicaly i want to avoid using  . $row['Country'] . , . $row['OrderNumber'] ., . $row['Region'] ..... and use a variable with explode and foreach value it will retrieve the data

Comment: Why? There's no sense in that.  Just reassign `$country = $row['county'];` if you don't want to type it out multiple times, then use `echo "<td>$country</td>";`

Comment: @clearshot66  the columns are not fixed. there is a drop down list where user select the columns they want to see and it's stored in this format col1,col3,col9,col12,col21... I want to explode this variable and retrieve only the data of these columns

Comment: database columns are fixed....

Comment: If you're attempting to hide columns based on select statment either bring it all in and hide it via javascript based on their selection, do ajax to only pull what is chosen, or set this up differently because right now it isn't very intuitive or clear..

Comment: So whats not working? It looks like it should do exectly what you want it to

Comment: @RiggsFolly i don't know what is the issue. for example if i select 2 values from the drop down list it works then choose another 2 values it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since each row is itself an associative array, you can just loop over that array.

```
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) {
        echo "<td>" . $columnValue . "</td>";  
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

And this approach would also work if you alias your columns when doing the query.

(Your explode() attempt should've worked though... The only problem I see is a missing ";" on the $Col line)

Comment: robot  thanks for your answer but still not working for me. it extract the data but the columns are doubled and each columns is shown twice in right side of the page.Here is my code. Can you please check it ? Thank you  <?php  
$query = 'SELECT '.$_POST['selectedColumns'].' FROM database.table1';
$columnName = $_POST["selectedColumns"];
$columnValue = explode(",",$columnName);
foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) {
echo "<td>" . $columnValue . "</td>";  }
echo "</tr>";} ?>